# How to navigate to other screen after the whole app has loaded?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Good day! Currently learning Nav 5 and so far this is what I have tried. I want to navigate to other screens depending on the result of the Firebase login check.
But what happens is the app renders 3times in the Splash screen, what I want is the 3rd or the final data. How can I know when the app is done re-rendering stuff.
This is what I have tried and I am fairly new to React navigation hopefully somebody could point me on how to do this properly. Thank you!

***APP.JS***

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      let logged = false
      if (user) {
        logged = true
        firebase.firestore().collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then(firestoreDocument => {
            if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
              return
            }
            const user = firestoreDocument.data()
            console.log("subs data", user)
            setUser(user)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            alert(error)
          })
      } else {
        setUser(null)
        logged = false
      }
      setIsLoggedIn(logged)
      setIsLogIncheckDone(true)
    })
    return subscriber // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, [])  
const getSomething = async () => {
    const data = {
      isLoggedIn, user, isLogInCheckDone
    }
    return data
  }

  if (!isLogInCheckDone) {
    return <SplashScreen />
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ GetSomething: getSomething }}>
      <ThemeContextProvider>
        <ThemeContextConsumer>
          {context =>
            (
              <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator theme={context.theme ? "dark" : "light"} >
                  <Stack.Screen name={"Splash"} component={SplashScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name={"Common"} component={CommonStackNav} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name={"Auth"} component={AuthStackNav} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name={"Dashboard"} component={DashboardStack} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name={"Verify"} component={VerificationStackNav} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                  <Stack.Screen name={"Wizard"} component={ProfileWizardStack} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
                <Toast ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
              </NavigationContainer>
            )
          }
        </ThemeContextConsumer>
      </ThemeContextProvider>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

***SPLASHSCREEN.JS***

```
export default function SplashScreen({ navigation, route }) {
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        const newData = appContext?.GetSomething()
        console.log("Splashy", newData)
//TODO Navigate here
    }, [appContext])
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <LottieView source={newSource} autoPlay loop />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logged state in your app.js to render what you want. Try something like this:

```
 return (
    <NavigationContainer >
      {logged ? <Screens you want to render if the user is logged /> : <SplashScreen />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

Comment: But still I want to navigate through the stack depending on the other conditions. That's why I want everything to go through splash first before routing to other screens. Since The app re renders 3 times so I want it to load once it is done getting the final states or conditions